# how to make a delete / put request in python

Tags: python, rest, httpwebrequest

I can make get or post request using urllib, but how do I make DELETE- and PUT-requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUT request can be performed by httplib2

http://code.google.com/p/httplib2

Answer (score 7):

The [requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) library can handle POST, PUT, DELETE, and all other HTTP methods, and is significantly less scary than urllib, httplib and their variants.

Answer (score 4):

You can override get_method with something like this:

```
def _make_request(url, data, method):
    request.urllib2.Request(url, data=data)
    request.get_method = lambda: method
```

Then you pass "DELETE" as method.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511598/how-to-make-http-delete-method-using-urllib2) answer covers the details.

Answer (score 1):

The method is set implicitly in the [urlopen](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html) call

When you provide the data parameter a POST will be used.

```
urllib.request.urlopen(url, data=None[, timeout])
```

I don't think it's possible to use a DELETE HTTP method with urlib because of this line:

> **Request.get_method()**
>   Return a string
>   indicating the HTTP request method.
>   This is only meaningful for HTTP
>   requests, and currently always returns
>   'GET' or 'POST'.

Consider using [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html), [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/), or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) instead .for better support of HTTP methods.

Answer (score 1):

http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html

If you're looking to work with HTTP in twisted using the client side I'd suggest checking that out. It demonstrates how you can really easily make a request using the agent class.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, urllib and urllib2 only support `GET` and `POST` requests. You should probably take a look at [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) or [httplib2](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/).

Comment: Support for other methods in `urllib`has been added. [Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The default HTTP methods in urllib library are POST and GET:

```
def get_method(self):
    """Return a string indicating the HTTP request method."""
    default_method = "POST" if self.data is not None else "GET"
    return getattr(self, 'method', default_method)
```

But we can override this get_method() function to get DELETE request:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(new_url)
req.get_method = lambda: "DELETE"
```