# How to make HTTP DELETE method using urllib2?

Tags: python, urllib2

Does `urllib2` support DELETE or PUT method? If yes provide with any example please. I need to use piston API.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

you can do it with [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html):

```
import httplib 
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection('www.foo.com')
conn.request('PUT', '/myurl', body) 
resp = conn.getresponse()
content = resp.read()
```

also, check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111945/is-there-any-way-to-do-http-put-in-python).  the accepted answer shows a way to add other methods to urllib2:

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
request = urllib2.Request('http://example.org', data='your_put_data')
request.add_header('Content-Type', 'your/contenttype')
request.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
url = opener.open(request)
```

Comment: It's you! Thanks for the examples using windows monitoring via wmi in Python, those were a great help for me :)

Comment: Nice.. httplib does not support authentication?

Comment: authentication with urllib2 in case of: `request.add_header( 'Authorization', b'Basic ' + 'user:password'.encode('base64').replace('\n','') )`

Answer (score 14):

Correction for Raj's answer:

```
import urllib2
class RequestWithMethod(urllib2.Request):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._method = kwargs.pop('method', None)
    urllib2.Request.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

  def get_method(self):
    return self._method if self._method else super(RequestWithMethod, self).get_method()
```

Comment: it would be shorter to use `self._method = kwargs.pop('method', None)`

Comment: The use of super gives me a _TypeError_. Instead I used `urllib2.Request.get_method(self)`

Answer (score 11):

Found following code from https://gist.github.com/kehr/0c282b14bfa35155deff34d3d27f8307 and it worked for me (Python 2.7.5):

```
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request(uri, data=data)
request.get_method = lambda: 'DELETE'
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Comment: So dirty-clean :/

Answer (score 7):

You can subclass the urllib2.Request object and override the method when you instantiate the class.

```
import urllib2

class RequestWithMethod(urllib2.Request):
  def __init__(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
    self._method = method
    urllib2.Request.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  def get_method(self):
    return self._method
```

Courtesy of [Benjamin Smedberg](http://benjamin.smedbergs.us/blog/2008-10-21/putting-and-deleteing-in-python-urllib2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a subclass of the `Request` object, and call it as follows:

```
import urllib2

class RequestWithMethod(urllib2.Request):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._method = kwargs.pop('method', None)
        urllib2.Request.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_method(self):
        return self._method if self._method else super(RequestWithMethod, self).get_method()


def put_request(url, data):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    request = RequestWithMethod(url, method='PUT', data=data)
    return opener.open(request)


def delete_request(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    request = RequestWithMethod(url, method='DELETE')
    return opener.open(request)
```

(This is similar to the above answers, but shows usage.)