# python: HTTP PUT with unencoded binary data

Tags: python, http, binary, put

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to perform an HTTP PUT request with verbatim binary data in Python 2.7 with the standard Python libraries.

I thought I could do it with urllib2, but [that fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983303/python-http-put-with-binary-data) because [`urllib2.Request`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) expects its data in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. I do not want to encode the binary data, I just want to transmit it verbatim, after the headers that include

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: (whatever my binary data length is)
```

This seems so simple, but I keep going round in circles and can't seem to figure out how.

How can I do this? (aside from open up a raw binary socket and write to it)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out my problem. It seems there is some obscure behavior in [`urllib2.Request`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) / [`urllib2.urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) (at least in Python 2.7)

The `urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)` constructor seems to expect the same type of string in its url and data parameters.

I was giving the data parameter raw data from a file `read()` call (which in Python 2.7 returns it in the form of a 'plain' string), but my url was accidentally Unicode because I concatenated a portion of the URL from the result of another function which returned Unicode strings.

Rather than trying to "downcast" `url` from Unicode -> plain strings, it tried to "upcast" the `data` parameter to Unicode, and it gave me a codec error. (oddly enough, this happens on the `urllib2.urlopen()` function call, not the `urllib2.Request` constructor)

When I changed my function call to

```
# headers contains `{'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'}`
r = urllib2.Request(url.encode('utf-8'), data, headers)
```

it worked fine.

Comment: I bumped into the [requests library](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests) just today. In the future, you might want to use that.

Answer (score 9):

You're misreading the documentation: [`urllib2.Request`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request) expects the data *already encoded*, and for POST that usually means the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. You are free to associate any other, *binary* data, like this:

```
import urllib2

data = b'binary-data'
r = urllib2.Request('http://example.net/put', data,
                    {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
r.get_method = lambda: 'PUT'
urllib2.urlopen(r)
```

This will produce the request you want:

```
PUT /put HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Content-Length: 11
Host: example.net
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Connection: close
User-Agent: Python-urllib/2.7

binary-data
```

Comment: But what I get is `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: btw, how did you get the raw request sent from urllib2?

Comment: @JasonS That's because your data is a *string* (a `unicode` object), not a `bytes` object. Encode it to the correct encoding with [`encode`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode). It can be helpful to write the program in Python 3 and then backport it to 2.x.

Comment: @JasonS Sorry, I don't understand your question. The code I used is right there in the answer. Notice the `b` in front of `b'binary-data'`, which makes it a `bytes` literal (although that has no effect in 2.x). Can you post the code that throws the `UnicodeDecodeError`?

Comment: I'll try to post a test case. For the record, I am *not* misreading the documentation. I understand about urllib2.Request; that was made clear in my other question. My question is how to use *any* Python libraries to `PUT` unencoded binary data.

Comment: @JasonS Well, of course it depends on the library you're using, but with urllib(2), you just set the `data` parameter of Request to the `bytes` object (= the binary data). Your problem is that you have a *string* (`unicode`), and need to convert it `bytes` (confusingly identical to `str` in Python 2.x, which despite the name is *not* a string).

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered/tried using [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html?highlight=httplib#httplib.HTTPConnection.request)?

**HTTPConnection.request(method, url[, body[, headers]])**

> This will send a request to the server using the HTTP request method
>   method and the selector url. If the body argument is present, it
>   should be a string of data to send after the headers are finished.
>   Alternatively, it may be an open file object, in which case the
>   contents of the file is sent; this file object should support fileno()
>   and read() methods. The header Content-Length is automatically set to
>   the correct value. The headers argument should be a mapping of extra
>   HTTP headers to send with the request.

Comment: "Have you considered/tried using httplib?" -- yes. Won't work, it pukes on non-ascii data.

Comment: Hmmm... open file object, well that might be of help.

Answer (score 1):

This snipped worked for me to PUT an image:

on HTTPS site.  If you don't need HTTPS, use
httplib.HTTPConnection(URL) instead.

```
import httplib
import ssl
API_URL="api-mysight.com"
TOKEN="myDummyToken"
IMAGE_FILE="myimage.jpg"
imageID="myImageID"
URL_PATH_2_USE="/My/image/" + imageID +"?objectId=AAA"
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/octet-stream", "X-Access-Token": TOKEN}
imgData = open(IMAGE_FILE, "rb")
REQUEST="PUT"
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(API_URL, context=ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1))
conn.request(REQUEST, URL_PATH_2_USE, imgData, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
result = response.read()
```