# github v3 API - delete / remove a repo

Tags: api, github, github-api, http-delete

I would like to programmatically delete a github repo, when setting up a unit test environment for my application.

I am already using the v3 API, which seems to be most supported and the path going forward. I am using the following python lines to successfully CREATE a repo, just fine:

```
import urllib2, base64
createData = '{\"name\": \"UnitTest-SubModules\", \"description\": \"This is a Fake repo used for testing\"}'
request = urllib2.Request("https://api.github.com/user/repos")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('user', 'pass')).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
result = urllib2.urlopen(request, data=createData)
```

How do I set this up to DELETE a repo? I cannot find the specification for deleting at http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/

I have tried, based off guestimating, the following code, as it follows the API pattern, but it did not work. Came back with urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

```
request = urllib2.Request("https://api.github.com/repos/nyeates/UnitTest-SubModules")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('user', 'pass')).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
request.get_method = lambda: 'DELETE'
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

I got the python http DELETE code from: [How to make HTTP DELETE method using urllib2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511598/how-to-make-http-delete-method-using-urllib2)

Comment: I don't think the v3 API allows you to delete repos. We've run into this issue as well and are waiting for an official response from them.

Comment: Also, this would be far more elegant written using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DELETE method is now here: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository

Comment: Is this also true for organisations? I have admin rights (eg I'm an owner) I tried to do this in curl for testing. 'curl -H "Authorization: token blarblar" -X DELETE -i api.github.com/repos/OrgName/Test5'; but it says 404 not found. The auth is working since it says my limit is 4980 and not 50odd. If I do it without the -X DELETE it returns all the details about the repo. so I have URL correct.

Comment: You probably haven't set the scope for your token. By default the scope of tokens don't allow to delete repositories.