# request to delete github repositorie

Tags: url, github, request, github-api

is there a url that I can make to delete my github repositorie?
In the deletion page there's a form with my token and etc, but how can I make a url to delete it?

Answer (score 1):

Beside the [manual deletion process](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-a-repo), there seems to be an API available.

As mentioned in "[github v3 API - delete / remove a repo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8920696/6309)", this wasn't fully supported earlier in January 2012. It could be supported now:
The [GitHub API V3 mentions](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository):

```
DELETE /repos/:owner/:repo
```